# How Can I restrict an integer input value?

Tags: java, int, restriction

Alright, I am making a HiLo game and I found an issue with the code. The player starts with 1000 points but they can place a bet higher than the number of points they have. I want it so they can not bet more than what they have

```
int playerPoints = 1000;
int betPoints;
int predict;
int randomNumber;

System.out.println("Enter the points you want to risk");
betPoints = input.nextInt();
```

I need betPoints to be less than or equal to playerPoints. How can I restrict the integer to obey that?

Comment: What should happen if they enter a number that's too high?

Comment: Place the input collection into a loop (like a `while` loop), add an if statement to check for validity, and then display an error and recollect if necessary. BTW, you also need to ensure they do not enter, presumably `<=0`.

Answer (score 2):

With `Math.min()` for example :

```
betPoints = Math.min(playerPoints, betPoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

change `betPoints = input.nextInt();` with,

```
do {
    betPoints = input.nextInt();
} while(betPoints > playerPoints);
```